# racket : I'm trying to build a function returning all values associated with key

Tags: racket

I have a list like (list (list key value) ... ) and I'm trying to build a function returning all values associated with key.

I tought I could use match construct to do so but without any success.

```
#lang racket

; should return a list starting with key, otherwise #f 
(define (match-key lst key)
  (match lst
      [(list key val) value]
      [_ #f]))
; testing data
(define test-lst 
  (list
   (list 'title "Lorem title") 
   (list 'price 999.99)
   (list 'colour "red")
   ))

(eq? "Lorem title" (match-key test-lst 'title)) ; should return #t
(eq? "Another lorem" (match-key test-lst 'title)) ; should return #f
(eq? 999.99 (match-key test-lst 'price)) ; should return #t
(eq? 111.11 (match-key test-lst 'price)) ; should return #f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structurally, the pattern `(list key val)` is not the same as `(list (list key val) ...)`. Since you have the latter as the structure of your dictionary, the only clause that gets matched in the procedure `match-key` becomes the last, where `_` indicates a pattern that matches any syntax object.

To use [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html?q=match#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match%29%29) for filtering a key-value pair list and return all associated values, you can do the following:

```
(define (filter/match lst key)
  (let ([has-key? (lambda (l) (equal? (car l) key))])
    (match lst
      ['()                   '()]
      [(cons (? has-key?) b) (cons (cadar lst) (filter/match b key))]
      [(cons a b)            (filter/match b key)])))
```

For example,

```
;; test data
(define test-lst 
  (list (list 'title "title1") 
        (list 'price 999.99)
        (list 'title "title2")
        (list 'colour "red")))

(filter/match test-lst 'title)
=> '("title1" "title2")
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Flist#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) to achieve this more simply, as follows:

```
(define (get-val lst key)
  (for/list ([l lst]
             #:when (equal? (car l) key))
    (cadr l)))
```

For example:

```
> (get-val test-lst 'title)
'("title1" "title2")
```

---

You can also look at the various built-in procedures available for working with [dictionaries](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/dicts.html). For example, using [`dict-ref`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/dicts.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fdict..rkt%29._dict-ref%29%29), you can do:

```
(dict-ref test-lst 'title #f)
=> '("title1")
(dict-ref test-lst 'rand-key #f)
=> #f
```

This returns the value for the first instance of key (hence, doesn't match all values associated with key). If no key matches are found, returns `#f`.